# Aggregating according to factor levels in R (create new columns?)

Tags: r, aggregate

I have an array of dates and an array of categories. I want to aggregate the array of categories by dates, counting the occurrences. If I just do:

```
array <- aggregate(array$category,by=list(array$date),FUN="length")
```

I will get the occurrences of all the categories. I want the occurrences per factor of the category.

I have several data, each with its own category. It varies from 5 to 9 categories, and in each date, you can have different categories.

An example data is:

```
category dateop
   3 05/07/2012
   3 05/07/2012
   4 05/07/2012
   4 05/07/2012
   4 05/07/2012
   4 05/07/2012
   5 05/07/2012
   5 05/07/2012
   5 05/07/2012
   3 05/07/2012
   3 05/07/2012
   3 05/07/2012
   3 03/07/2012
   1 04/07/2012
   5 05/07/2012
   5 05/07/2012
   5 05/07/2012
   5 05/07/2012
   5 05/07/2012
   3 05/07/2012
```

I guess that I have to create new arrays that will keep the occurrences of each category. I have written a function that does a for loop over each level and creates a new array, but I was wondering if there was a faster (and with less code) way to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: @akrun, I think OP is looking for `library(data.table) ; setDT(array)[, .N, .(category, date)]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes, I didn't test it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here are two possible simple solutions (I'll call your data set `df`, though it's not any better name than `array`)

```
library(data.table)  
setDT(df)[, .(occurrences  = .N), .(date, category)]

#          date category occurrences
# 1: 05/07/2012        3           6
# 2: 05/07/2012        4           4
# 3: 05/07/2012        5           8
# 4: 03/07/2012        3           1
# 5: 04/07/2012        1           1
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(date, category) %>%
  summarise(occurrences = n())

# Source: local data table [5 x 3]
# Groups: date
# 
#         date category occurrences
# 1 05/07/2012        3           6
# 2 05/07/2012        4           4
# 3 05/07/2012        5           8
# 4 03/07/2012        3           1
# 5 04/07/2012        1           1
```

Or with base R

```
df$occurrences <- 1
aggregate(occurrences ~ date + category, df, sum)
#         date category occurrences
# 1 04/07/2012        1           1
# 2 03/07/2012        3           1
# 3 05/07/2012        3           6
# 4 05/07/2012        4           4
# 5 05/07/2012        5           8
```

---

And @akruns uber vectorized solution

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(df[2:1])), !!Freq)
```

Comment: I appreciate the input, thanks! I like more the solution with dplyr, but I guess it is a thing of taste.

Comment: You can easily do it with base R too, see my edit, though my tool of choice is always `data.table`.